# UWP WebView in RelativePanel does not display web page

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, relativepanel

I have 3 `WebView` each in a `PivotItem` inside a `RelativePanel` like that:

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Pivot Name="pivot"
           RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
        <PivotItem Header="Slack LiveTile">
            <WebView Name="webView_001" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Slack RDV Tech">
            <WebView Name="webView_002" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="WhatsApp">
            <WebView Name="webView_003" />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>

    <CommandBar
        RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" />

</RelativePanel>
```

My problem is that the WebView content is not shown and I do not understand why. Before using a `RelativePanel`, I used a `Grid` and it worked well.

Can you explain why it does not work?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you will also need `RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"` on your `Pivot` to stretch to fill the entire space, otherwise it will only take space that's enough for the `PivotHeader`s.

Comment: Thank you! I have added `RelativePanel.Above="commandBar"` to stretch up to the top of the `CommandBar`.